# Incorporate gRPC Server in Chaincode

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, grpc, hyperledger-chaincode

So I'm using gRPC to connect my Hyperledger Fabric network(server) to my Android app(client). Server side is written in Go and works with Android when server is brought up and not connected to chaincode(does nothing).

How do I just transfer server.go code into my chaincode?
Can I just copy this into my chaincode code and it would work as a server and chaincode in one, when brought up in Docker?
Or do I somehow call chaincode from server.go file, while I got them all up? (whole network in docker, server.go and android)

***server.go***

```
package main

import (
    "context"
    "log"
    "net"
    "fmt"

    grpc "google.golang.org/grpc"
    pb "../proto"
)

func main() {
    listener, err := net.Listen("tcp", ":8080")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Unable to listen on port 8080:  %v", err)
    }

    grpcServer := grpc.NewServer()
    pb.RegisterBlockchainAndroidServer(grpcServer, &Server{})
    grpcServer.Serve(listener)
}

// Server struct
type Server struct{}

// LogInUser implementation
func (s *Server) LogInUser(ctx context.Context, in *pb.User) (*pb.Success, error) {
    fmt.Println("bloyal logInUser\n")
    fmt.Println("User email: " + in.GetEmail() + ", user pass: " + in.GetPassword())

    return &pb.Success{Success: true}, nil
}
```

***chaincode.go*** - just main()

```
func main() {
    err := shim.Start(new(SimpleChaincode))
    fmt.Printf("Main entered!! ")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("Error starting Simple chaincode: %s", err)
    }

    listener, err := net.Listen("tcp", ":8080")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Unable to listen on port 8080:  %v", err)
    }

    grpcServer := grpc.NewServer()
    proto.RegisterBlockchainAndroidServer(grpcServer, &Server{})
    grpcServer.Serve(listener)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What are you trying to achieve?

`chaincode.go`  as-is starts a chaincode (`shim.Start`) and starts a gRPC server but there's no connectivity between the 2 and so they exist but are entirely distinct.

IIRC Fabric uses `init` and `invoke` methods for chaincode defined by an interface. `main` is for testing. So, this approach may be incorrect.

Fabric providess a gRPC API for its own purposes and you should be able to leverage this (existing API and services) using an Android client. If that's insufficient, you can build your own.

Calling gRPC methods from **within** chaincode may (!) be more challenging. One common (always?) requirement with smart contacts (chaincode) is that these be deterministic; the same function must be (re)runnable at any time and must produce the same output for the same input, e.g. 2+2=4 is deterministic but "What's the time now?" Is not and, because of not being able to control|ensure availability etc., many times (not always) external API calls are not either.

I don't know whether chaincode permits external calls but, for the reason described above, it may not.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! My Android client should invoke my chaincode for simple checkLogin, getPoints etc functions. I figured to do this with gRPC but I don't know where to implement server side, so android gRPC calls can be recieved and chaincode called?

Comment:  I'm no longer familiar with Fabric but this link may help. If the documentation is exhaustive (hopefully another person can confirm?), it appears that there's only a REST (not gRPC) API for invoking methods on chaincode: https://openblockchain.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Setup/Chaincode-setup/

Comment: ... There's little benefit in wrapping a REST API in a gRPC API

Comment: @DazWilkin that's a link to documentation of Fabric 0.6 (2016) which is extinct by now. Fabric v1.0 and onwards doesn't have a REST API that can invoke chaincode. The peer has a limited REST API for doing simple administration tasks such as logging control, metrics, etc.

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to incorporate your web application into a smart contract is to get rid of all the REST wiring and just get the [payloads and parameters](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/blob/release-1.4/core/chaincode/shim/interfaces.go#L34) from the transaction proposal and feed them directly into pure application level functions. Meaning, the client will send the parameters through an official Fabric SDK (Go, Java, Node.js).

The peer authenticates the proposal from the client for you, so you don't need to check "login" but you can assume that the creator (signer) of the proposal indeed signed the proposal that contains the parameters.

Since Fabric uses x509 certificates for clients/nodes, the correct way to represent users is by their corresponding certificates (or parts of them).